# Topology: "Choosing" versus asserting existence

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

My question is a bit more general, but I have a concrete proof where this distinction comes out, working from Munkres's topology book. The proof concerns equivalent descriptions of a basis. Here is a paraphrase of the lemma.

> Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology on $X$ generated by the basis $\mathcal{T}$. Then $\mathcal{T}$ is equal to the set of all arbitrary unions of the basis elements.

For concreteness, let's call $\mathcal{T}'$ the set of all unions of the basis elements. The first direction $\mathcal{T}' \subset \mathcal{T}$ is fine. The backward direction presents the issue I was talking about. The proof I want to write looks something like this.

> Let $U \in \mathcal{T}$. Therefore, by definition of the topology generated by $\mathcal{T}$, for every $x \in U$, we can choose a basis element $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subset U$. I claim that $U = \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x$. Indeed, $u \in U$, we have $u \in B_u \subset \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x$. Conversely, $B_x \subset U$ for every $x \in U$, so $\bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x \subset U$.

This is where the subtlety comes in, because the lecturer I'm watching and Munkres both do not write "choose" a basis element. Rather, they say something to the effect of "for every $x \in U$, there is a basis element $B_x$," and then writes down the same union.

Which of these are correct, or are they both correct? Just asserting existence seems insufficient to me, because I haven't brought the basis element (a specific one) into existence. If I say there exists a basis element, there could be many of them, and it's hard to write down a union when $B_x$ for some $x \in U$ isn't well-defined.

Is this something that is just regarded as "assumed," or am I missing something? I find myself modifying a lot of my old proofs to use the "choose" language over "there exists."

Comment: From what I remember, Munkres accepts the Axiom of Choice, so "choosing" here is unproblematic.

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what worries you, but your proof is fine assuming the axiom of choice. Otherwise one can consider the set $V^\prime := \left\{B \in \mathcal B \ | \ \exists x \in U: x \in B \land B \subseteq U\right\}$. You can then prove that $\bigcup V^\prime = U$ and $V^\prime \in \mathcal T^\prime$. This proves the result in a choice free way!

Comment: @user2628206 So in other words, it doesn't even matter which element of $V'$ I "choose" or whose existence I asserted, because they all just give the same union?

Comment: Don’t use $\mathcal T$ for both the topology and the basis.

Comment: As long as one has enough elements of $V^\prime$ such that one achieves a cover of $U$, then one is fine. But there is no reason to not just take the whole set $V^\prime$ in this case. (In my first comment $\mathcal B$ was the basis you where working wth, consider ThomasAndrews' remark)

Comment: For every $x\in U$ there is a basis element does not need the axiom of choice. The basis element exists by the definition of a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. "Choosing" means "choosing any one of the ones that are known to exist". You do not need to specify a particular one, you only need to know that the set of them is not empty. That there are many choices does not invalidate the argument.

Formally speaking,  "choosing" depends subtly on the axiom of choice, but whether you say "choosing" or "there exists" does not deal with the subtlety.